# Как убрать послению запятую в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно между всеми словами из списка поставить запятую, при этом, чтобы последняя запятая не отображалась.

```
x = ["Мазерати", "Бугати верон", "Ламборгине", "жыгули"]
print("Список", end=':')
for item in x:
    print(item, end=",")
```

В конце выходит:

Список:Мазерати,Бугат верон,Ламборгине,жыгули,

Проблема в последней запятой.

Comment: `print(",".join(x))`

Comment: `print(*x, sep=", ")`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["Мазерати", "Бугати верон", "Ламборгине", "жыгули"]
print("Список", end=':')
for item in x:
    print(item, end=",")
'''
Список:Мазерати,Бугати верон,Ламборгине,жыгули,Для продолжения нажмите любую кла
вишу . . .
'''

print('\b','\b')
'''
Список:Мазерати,Бугати верон,Ламборгине,жыгули
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
'''
```

но предпочтительнее ответы в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["Мазерати", "Бугати верон", "Ламборгине", "жыгули"]
print("Список", end=':')
for item in x:
    if item!=x[len(x)-1]:
        print(item, end=',')
    else:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ,но не мог бы ты ответить по подробней то что находится в сточке if

Comment: В if-е находится проверка на то, не является ли item последним, если является последним, то выполняется else

Comment: тоесть если там бы стояла цифра или слово оно бы удалилось ?Суть в том что [len(x)-1] это означает что оно считает сколько там всего с запятой и получается 8 еще -1 и 7.Если я утверждаю правильно тогда на 7 раз item было бы ровно 7 и тогда бы удалялся не последний елемент а предпоследний.Также почему перед [len(x)-1] стоит х

Comment: У кода похоже есть проблема - а если в списке есть элемент, равный последнему?

Comment: @Tormoz, нет, тогда бы вывелось последнее сообщение без запятой.